# A more efficient method for electrolysis?

Tags: electrolysis

If you made the anode and cathode both out of a single piece of zeolite that has been coated inside with graphite (or graphene) wouldn’t that provide a conductive path and greater surface area thus making electrolysis of water more efficient?

Comment: You don't really need greater surface.

Comment: That's a good question, but keep in mind there is still a diffusion barrier. Zeolites use to trap stuff, and for an effective electrolysis you need the products to be exchanged rapidly.